# i want to create a simple dotnet(vb.net or c#.net) class

Tags: c#, vb.net, api

I have a small task. I need the a .net class library created that communicates with a RPC REST service. All I need is the basic framework. So if you can just get it to pass the API token and get back the login credential 
    https://simplybook.me/en/api/developer-api/tab/explorer_api

```
The have a sample API Key I think you can use:

company: mib
API key: f43618e37b82004066d60db3431f4a06392599a6cfcafa8268bf25becc0ec7d7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JSONRPC Client as shown below [Link](https://github.com/adamashton/json-rpc-csharp)

```
using (Client rpcClient = new Client("someURL"))
{
    rpcClient.Headers.Add("X-Application", "MyApplicationKey");

    Request request = rpcClient.NewRequest("SportsAPING/v1.0/listMarketBook");
    GenericResponse response = rpcClient.Rpc(request);

    if (response.Result != null)
    {
        JToken result = response.Result;
    }
    else
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Error in response, code:{0} message:{1}",
            response.Error.Code, response.Error.Message);


    // Example with positional parameters
    JArray parameters = JArray.Parse(@"['Small', 'Medium', 'Large' ]");
    Request resuestWithPostionalParameters = rpcClient.NewRequest("SportsAPING/v1.0/listMarketBook", parameters);

    // Example with named parameters
    JObject namedParameters = JObject.Parse(@"{ CPU: 'Intel', }");
    Request resuestWithNamedParameters = rpcClient.NewRequest("SportsAPING/v1.0/listMarketBook", namedParameters);
}
```

Comment: above code is sample code you can add nuget `JsonRPC` in your project or code can be found on [link](https://github.com/adamashton/json-rpc-csharp)